# How to randomizing the background?

Tags: java, android

I have to make an app, whick is when you click somewhere, changing his background. How can I do that? And can I do that, with the drawable folder? Example I make 10 different images, that i copy to the drawable folder. Can I randomize the 10 different images, when I click somewhere?
*Edit*
I didn't try anything, because I don't know where can I start

Comment: This is a description of the problem but not **what you've tried**. You also don't need to **BOLD** every **OTHER** word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED BASED ON REQUEST WITH EXAMPLE

```
     final RelativeLayout rootLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myRootLayout);
    final Random random = new Random(3); //generates 0 to 2 (as you set seed of 3 digits starting from 0)

    final List<Integer> myBackgroundImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myBackgroundImages.add(R.drawable.add_person);
    myBackgroundImages.add(R.drawable.add_photo_album);
    myBackgroundImages.add(R.drawable.add_key_box);


    rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rootLayout.setBackground(myBackgroundImages.get(random.nextInt()); //will be 0, 1, or 2
        }
    });
```

I did all this inside onCreate just to show you an example, but you don't need final on the values unless you are doing them in the same method like above. I would recommend making your list a variable in the class as well as your layout and setting the click listener else where, but this should be enough to demonstrate how it works for you.

OLD ANSWER LEFT FOR HISTORY

Of course there are many ways to do this. You can do this through binding if you are using data binding, just have a drawable property that you are bound to in your XML file.

If you are not using binding, then simply put an ID on your background root element like `<RelativeLayout id = some id that you will use`

then in code just update it. someIdThatYouUse.setBackground(R.drawables.myDrawable1).

if you are asking how to randomize it then there are multiple ways. You can name each drawable like random_1 and random_2 then create a random generator like String num = (new Random(9).nextInt() + 1).toString().

then make your name from it "random_" + num to get the resource by name.
Or you can make a list of drawables like

myList.add(R.drawable.myfirstone)
myList.add(R.drawable.someotherImage)
etc..

then create random number from 0 to 9.

then rootLayout.setBackground(myList.get(randomNumber));
of course make sure you check OS version and use correct setBackground vs setBackgroundDrawable to make sure you are compatible with your minimum support.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain me more precisely? I have in my drawable 5 images (id's: blue, yellow, green, black and red), that's have 1080x1920 resolution. When I tap anywhere on the screen, I want the app to change his background randomly.

Comment: Here I'll update my answer, you are probably just over thinking it